Effect when Survey123 Connect form is updated and new feature layer is created
My survey_results edits are no longer syncing when the feature layer is loaded in ArcGIS Pro.
I believe the following to be my issue:
"When republishing a survey from ArcGIS Survey123 Connect, a new hosted feature layer of the survey is generated in the survey folder (Survey-SurveyName) in ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS, but the results feature layer view (SurveyName_results) still references the old feature layer of the survey. The viewing permission in ArcGIS Survey123 still references the previously configured sharing settings of the results feature layer view."
Will updating the _results configuration to the new feature layer alter the associated dashboard? Will I have to also point the dashboard to the new layer? Will submitters using the form need to do anything on their end to have access to the now updated form?
I am not the creator on these apps and am trying not to break them!
